# Is it possible to big on AdWords to get traffic and the use AdSense to make more than that?

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads

I am using AdSense on my website, and my CPC is about 0.15 €.

Later I started using AdWords to get more people to my site. I paid for every AdWords click for example 0.1 €. Traffic that came from AdWords and clicked on my AdSense ad on my website didn't give me 0.15€ as organic traffic, but it gave me maximally the amount that I paid for that click in AdWords (so that means max.0,1€ in this example)

I am frustrated because I was searching everywhere and I can't find the relevant answer.

I just want to know if it is possible to pay in AdWords 0.1€ and get paid out in AdSense 0.15€ and if it is possible to tell me how.

Is it possible to profit from this type of one-time user?

---

EDIT
I don't need to know that it is not possible to make every user click or how many CPM do I need.

**1.** I want to know if it is possible to do somehow that my CPC will be higher than PPC.
**2.** If it is not possible can I change it to be the closest possible to it?

Comment: How you can be sure, the user who clicks on your adwords ads will surely clicks on your adsense ads? May be you're getting 10 clicks from ads so may be only 1 user will click on your adsense ads. Are you new to Adsense and Have you used GDN before?

Comment: It is just theory; I don't need everyone to click the ad

Comment: @JakubKliský, so you didn't give bounty to anyone. Why?

Comment: Because no one could answer the question...or explain why I am thinking wrong

Comment: You have three answers mate. All three are correct and on topic. I don't know what do you want to hear? Answer is No, and you have explanations why. And no one answered you? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do has a name:  **Click Arbitrage**.   You buy clicks from once source and then create a page with ads that make on average more than you are paying.

Click arbitrage can indeed be a viable business model.  To make it work you need find cheap traffic and direct that traffic to a higher value target.   Ideally you can identify users that aren't being targeted by advertisers properly and you target the users better than other advertisers can.   If you can put more relevant ads in front of a user than what they were seeing before your site, you have the chance of making money.

There are lots of guides and articles floating around the internet with tactics and tricks to try.   I'm not going to link to them.  You can search and find some.   The click arbitrage field is filled with spammers.  It is very hard to do a good job at click arbitrage while also serving users well.  Many times, arbitrage pages end up filled with ads and provide very little value to users.   Google tends to kick such advertisers out of both AdWords and AdSense.

You probably won't be able to use AdWords and AdSense alone to make this happen.   Google maintains deep marketplaces with tons of sites participating.  There are few areas in that marketplace where there are still arbitrage opportunities.   If you do find some places where you can arbitrage, your AdSense advertisers will likely end up bidding on your AdWords keywords directly before too long.

Comment: Thank you :) I will stick to the fair web monetizing then

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you want is to pay 0.10€ on AdWords, click on it and get 0.15€ on AdSense?

If you have two apples and eat one, how many apples would you have? Two? I don't think so.

So, let me answer briefly on your question:

> I just want to know if it is possible to pay in AdWords 0.1€ and get
>   paid out in AdSense 0.15€.

**No.**

Comment: I see it like "If you give someone an apple and he is happy with that he will give you better apple."

Comment: You need to see it like 2 -1 = 1

Comment: Try to explain it please :D

Comment: If you give 10 cents to something, how can you get 15 back?

Comment: if I give you 10 cents now, would you return 15 cents to me in few minutes?

Comment: Isn't it all about the advertiser (how much is he going to pay) and about the country tier ([link](http://software-mall.blogspot.sk/2013/05/list-of-tier-1-tier-2-tier-3-countries.html))?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49237/discussion-between-jakub-klisky-and-josip-ivic).

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't work in way you describe it, so the answer is no in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set income from AdSense. There's no way to guarantee a click from a user.

Average income for AdSense tends to work along these lines:

> A website serving an average of 3 pages per visit, each with 2 ad
>   units and an impression CPM of $1 would therefore earn $6 per 1000
>   visits.

In order to guarantee a profit from Adwords, you would need a CPC of $0.006

This means what you'd like to achieve (purchasing traffic, making higher returns from out bound clicks) is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand Adsense and Adwords clearly.

Let's talk about Adsense CPC

So the adsense CPC depend on keywords on webpage?

No, it's purely depend on what kind of visitor you're getting. For example I have search some cloud related stuff in Google search and some other user search about android game related stuff, and we both land in your website, then I will see cloud ads and from my clicks you'll get $1 and second user will see android game ads, and from that clicks, you might get only $0.10. No matter what kind of website you have for example gaming, news, portal, any niche blog etc.

Example : Let's say you have create one ads "learn php loop" and you send visitor to your blog post, so do you think all will have same interest?, might be some people will see hosting related ads, which will give you only $0.07 per clicks. And other might don't even click.

The visitor you're getting from Adwords is purely based on your ads campaign targeting option, 90 % advertiser on adword always used interest based ads, so the way you think it will not going to work.

I don't know what's in your mind, but again I want to say You might get 20 user from Google ads and might only one click on your ads. Buying traffic on Adsense website is not my first choice. Whatever traffic source you use, but lower quality traffic may not give you better CPC on adsnese. Adsense generally works great for organic traffic. If you still want to test paid traffic, then I wil say go with FB PPC.